# Connection Timeout Error with Hostinger Business Plan

Tags: http-status-code-503

I am using hostinger.in to host my domain under Business Plan - Shared Server.

I have a PHP page which sends Bulk emails to my subscribers using PHPMailer and AMAZON SES as SMTP. But after some times, I am getting error  `503 Service Unavailable` when I am trying to run PHP Page.

Spoke to Hostinger support, and they say go for VPS.

Comment: Current Setting : max_execution_time : 5000